# Drawing images with float coordinates

Tags: java, image, draw, graphics2d

I want to draw an image that moves slowly with fractional coordinates so the movement is smoother. The image is very small (5x7 pixels). I thought that Graphics2D might have a way to draw an image at a fractional location using anti-aliasing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can antialiase lines and curves drawn via the Graphics object, but not images. I can't imagine how that could be done in real time. And floating coordinates is confusing to me since Java resolution is to the pixel. How can you draw a fraction of a pixel?

Comment: It is a very simple greyscale image thats only 5x7 pixels, so I think there is a way to use anti-aliasing to simulate a half of a pixel, like cleartype.

Comment: OK, but you'll have to create the code for this algorithm yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the image using an [`AffineTransform` translate instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getTranslateInstance%28double,%20double%29) - it accepts doubles.

Comment: Thank you- I knew something like this was possible.